# Checkbox: can't check checkbox in Safari

Tags: wordpress, checkbox

i've created a contact form with Contact Form 7 Plugin (Wordpress) checkbox but i can't chech them in Safari.
How can i solve it? http://www.r90.ch/contact-form/

CSS:

```
.myinput[type="checkbox"]{ 
width: 11px !important;
height: 11px !important;
border: 1px solid #808080 !important; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code for checkbox style

```
<style>
        .regular-checkbox {
            -webkit-appearance: none;
            background-color: #fafafa;
            border: 1px solid #cacece;
            box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05), inset 0px -15px 10px -12px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
            padding: 9px;
            border-radius: 3px;
            display: inline-block;
            position: relative;
        }

        .regular-checkbox:checked:after {
            content: '\2714';
            font-size: 14px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            left: 3px;
            color: #99a1a7;
        }
        </style>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1-1" class="regular-checkbox" />
```